# Add events to a NodeList

Tags: javascript

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/#tidier-event-binding-with-queryselectorall demonstrates an approach of adding events to a `NodeList`:

```
var unboundForEach = Array.prototype.forEach,
    forEach = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundForEach);

forEach(document.querySelectorAll('.klasses'), function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', someFunction);
});
```

I don't quite understand two things:

1. Why does it need to `bind` the `unboundForEach`?
2. Why does it use `Function.prototype.call.bind` instead of `Function.prototype.bind`?

Answer (score 1):

What `.bind` does is it creates a function similar to the original function, except:

- The first argument is the `this` value to be used inside the function
- The second, third, fourth, etc arguments passed to the bound function are passed as the first, second, and third etc arguments to the function

Using `.bind` here is one way of allowing for the creation a function that can take a collection as the first parameter (the `this`) and a callback as the second parameter. That said, as you've noticed, the way they're constructing this is pretty confusing.

```
var unboundForEach = Array.prototype.forEach,
    forEach = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundForEach);
```

To unpack this - when `.call` is used, it requires a `this` of the function to be invoked. For example

```js
function fn() {
  console.log(this.foo);
}
fn.call({ foo: 'foo' });
```

The above invokes `Function.prototype.call` with a `this` value of `fn`. The argument passed in is then used as the `this` value when `fn` is called. Equivalently, you could do

```js
function fn() {
  console.log(this.foo);
}
const invokeFnWithAThisOfTheArgument = Function.prototype.call.bind(fn);
invokeFnWithAThisOfTheArgument({ foo: 'foo' });
```

Your code's `Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundForEach);` is doing the same thing - `.bind` is used so that `.call`'s `this` is bound to the prototype method, so that the prototype method is what gets invoked when the function returned by `.call` gets invoked.

> Why does it use `Function.prototype.call.bind` instead of `Function.prototype.bind`?

Using only `.bind`

```
forEach = Function.prototype.bind(unboundForEach);
```

would mean that you'd eventually be invoking `Function.prototype` with a `this` value of `unboundForEach`. But `Function.prototype` doesn't do anything with its arguments or parameters - it's a no-op.

---

Now, while you *can* use the `.call.bind` approach, it's pretty hard to decipher. I'd highly recommend against it, and instead do something like

```
document.querySelectorAll('.klasses').forEach(
```

or, for the more general case, write out a higher-order function

```
const bindToNew = (fn) => (thisToPassToFn, ...args) => {
  return fn.apply(thisToPassToFn, args);
};
const forEach = bindToNew(Array.prototype.forEach);
forEach(document.querySelectorAll('.klasses'), function (el) {
```

Answer (score 0):

### Stand alone `forEach`

The posted `forEach` function uses the syntax

```
forEach( arrrayLikeObject, callback)
```

similar to jQuery's `$.forEach` utility function, excepting that the callback arguments are those used by `Array.prototype.forEach` and the function won't iterate over enumerable keys of objects that are not array like - `Array.prototype.forEach` is intentionally generic and can be called on objects that are not instances of Array.

Calling the function with a node list argument serves as an example of calling it with an array-like argument.

#### Using Array.prototype.forEach

One of the ways to call `forEach` on an array-like object is

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arrayLike, callback)
```

where

1. `Array.prototype.forEach` is a function object to be called which needs an array like object as its `this` value ,
2. `Function.prototype.call` is a function method to call its `this` value, a function object, using the `this` value supplied as its first argument and passing any remaining argument values to the called function.

Normally `call` is inherited through the prototype chain of whatever function it is called on, and sees the function it is called on as its `this` value.

Looking closely at `forEach.call`,

1. `forEach` inherits `call` from `Function.prototype` on which `forEach` is prototyped.

   - `call` can be directly accessed as `Function.prototype.call`
2. `call` has a `this` value of `forEach` because its called on the `forEach` (function) object.

   - The `this` value of call can be set in an exotic function created by `Function.prototype.bind`

Hence to set the `this` value of `call` to `forEach` we can use

```
 const callForEach = Function.prototype.call.bind( Array.prototype.forEach);
```

Note the order of method calls: `bind` is being called on `call`, and `forEach` becomes the bound function's `this` value.

All that's left now is to write the stand-alone `forEach` function using the `callForEach` trick:

```
function forEach( arrayLikeOject, callback) {
    const callForEach = Function.prototype.call.bind( Array.prototype.forEach);
    callForEach( arrayLikeObject, callBack);
}
```

This is equivalent to the posted code.

#### Answers

**Q1**  Why does it need to bind`unboundForEach`?
**A1**  It doesn't. It binds `Function.prototype.call` using `Array.prototype.forEach` as its `this` value.

**Q2** Why does it use `Function.prototype.call.bind` instead of `Function.prototype.bind?`
**A2**  It does use `Function.prototype.bind` - but it's being inherited by `call`, the function object being bound.

### Variable names

It would seem the biggest problem here is a variable name chosen by the original authors: `unboundForEach` makes readers infer there is a bound version of `forEach` somewhere. There isn't.